# Obtaining Google Calendar In Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-calendar-api

Im trying to code an application which does the following:

- Retrieves Google calendar events
- Uses the Location in the google event and stores it locally

Ive managed to setupthe GoogleAPi up to my project and have enabled the relevant APi's. However im not entirely sure how to go around obtaining the said information.

Any guidance or links to material would be extremely helpful

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The problem im having is trying to retrieve Google calender entries, as i would have to store them in a relevant database/view. Then manipulate the data to extract the geo-locational co-ordinates for use in another variable. The reason i am posting on here is due to struggling to find a solution to obtain the relevant information as most applications prefer to add entries not request

Comment: The documentation is a great place to start.  https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars

Answer (score 9):

Although Google has pretty good API documentation, there are almost no examples in Swift especially when it comes to Calendar API. So I understand your frustration.

First of all, you're lucky, because libraries are available, and you don't have to manually implement network calls for login and calendar API. If you use Cocoapods (I strongly recommend) add the following pods:

```
target 'YourApp' do
    pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Calendar'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
end
```

If you don't use Cocoapods you can find them on github. The names of the libraries are self explanatory. `GoogleAPIClientForREST/Calendar` is written in Objective-C and at least in my case I had to create a bridging header file with the following imports:

```
#ifndef MyApp_Bridging_Header_h
#define MyApp_Bridging_Header_h

#import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.h>
#import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcherService.h>

#endif
```

In order for the calendar library to fetch calendars, events, etc., you need to have a logged in user. So first you need implement the login. Make sure you configure the Google sign-in service correctly. Don't forget to set the scopes.

```
import GoogleSignIn

func initGoogle() {
    // Initialize sign-in
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(String(describing: configureError))")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "your_client_id_string"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}
```

Implement `GIDSignInDelegate` methods and deal with their callbacks accordingly (because you can fetch calendars only when a user is logged in). To start login flow:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

Assuming all configurations were correct you should be able to login successfully.

When you have a Google session, then fetch calendar data. This is where a lot of reverse engineering will happen, because the calendar library is not very well documented. Consult the API reference in order to understand the relationships between different models: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/

But before you fetch calendar data, you need to create calendar service object:

```
import GoogleAPIClientForREST
import GoogleSignIn

/// Creates calendar service with current authentication
fileprivate lazy var calendarService: GTLRCalendarService? = {
    let service = GTLRCalendarService()
    // Have the service object set tickets to fetch consecutive pages
    // of the feed so we do not need to manually fetch them
    service.shouldFetchNextPages = true
    // Have the service object set tickets to retry temporary error conditions
    // automatically
    service.isRetryEnabled = true
    service.maxRetryInterval = 15

    guard let currentUser = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser,
        let authentication = currentUser.authentication else {
            return nil
    }

    service.authorizer = authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
    return service
}()
```

And finally get events for a calendar ID:

```
// you will probably want to add a completion handler here
func getEvents(for calendarId: String) {
    guard let service = self.calendarService else {
        return
    }

    // You can pass start and end dates with function parameters
    let startDateTime = GTLRDateTime(date: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))
    let endDateTime = GTLRDateTime(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24))

    let eventsListQuery = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsList.query(withCalendarId: calendarId)
    eventsListQuery.timeMin = startDateTime
    eventsListQuery.timeMax = endDateTime

    _ = service.executeQuery(eventsListQuery, completionHandler: { (ticket, result, error) in
        guard error == nil, let items = (result as? GTLRCalendar_Events)?.items else {
            return
        }

        if items.count > 0 {
            print(items)
            // Do stuff with your events
        } else {
            // No events
        }
    })
}
```

`GTLRCalendar_Event` among others has `location` property.

In order to fetch other data like calendar list, free-busy info, create events, etc., you'll have to do a bit of reverse engineering like I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you pls suggest how i can get events from other than primary calendar? this code is working if i write calendar id as "primary" but if i am passing other id as sting it returning 404 error , while i am having many events in my calender.

Comment: @Shilpa are you sure the calendar whose id you're passing has correct access permissions? Check that on your calendar settings page.

Comment: You are right, there are almost no Google Calendar Swift examples. And usually, Objective-C ones are outdated...

Comment: FYI if you don't need access to all calendar permissions (read, write, delete), check for permissions constants starting with kGTLR -- such as "kGTLRAuthScopeCalendarReadonly" to only grant read permissions. Set this constant in the scopes array.